# Scala Slick lambdas throwing compiler error

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

Having an issue mapping an object with nested objects to Slick (`2.1.0`). The compiler errors are:

```
[error] Subscriber.scala:42: value ~ is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Column[String]
[error]     identityId ~ 
[error]                ^
[error] Subscriber.scala:55: not found: value <>
[error]   <> (
```

Here's my code, any idea what's wrong? Why doesn't the compiler like my lambda?

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._

case class Subscriber(
  val identityId: IdentityId,
  val firstName: String,
  val lastName: String,
  val fullName: String,
  val email: Option[String],
  val avatarUrl: Option[String],
  val authMethod: AuthenticationMethod,
  val oAuth1Info: Option[OAuth1Info],
  val oAuth2Info: Option[OAuth2Info],
  val passwordInfo: Option[PasswordInfo]

) extends Identity

/* Table mapping
 */
class SubscribersTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Subscriber](tag, "trial_subscribers") {

  def identityId = column[String]("identity_id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def firstName = column[String]("first_name", O.NotNull)
  def lastName = column[String]("last_name", O.NotNull)
  def fullName = column[String]("full_name", O.NotNull)
  def email = column[String]("email")
  def avatarUrl = column[String]("avatar_url")
  def authMethod = column[String]("auth_method")
  def oAuth1Token = column[String]("oauth_1_token")
  def oAuth1Secret = column[String]("oauth_1_secret")
  def oAuth2AccessToken= column[String]("oauth_2_access_token")
  def oAuth2TokenType = column[String]("oauth_2_token_type")
  def oAuth2ExpiresIn = column[String]("oauth_2_expires_in")
  def oAuth2RefreshToken = column[String]("oauth_2_refresh_token")
  def passwordHasher = column[String]("password_hasher")
  def password = column[String]("password")
  def passwordSalt = column[String]("password_salt")

  def * =
    identityId ~
    firstName ~
    lastName ~
    fullName ~
    avatarUrl ~
    authMethod ~
    oAuth1Token ~
    oAuth1Secret ~
    oAuth2TokenType ~
    oAuth2ExpiresIn ~
    oAuth2RefreshToken ~
    passwordHasher ~
    password ~
    passwordSalt
  <> (
    /* from a row to an object */
    (
      identityId,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      fullName,
      avatarUrl,
      authMethod,
      oAuth1Token,
      oAuth1Secret,
      oAuth2TokenType,
      oAuth2ExpiresIn,
      oAuth2RefreshToken,
      passwordHasher,
      password,
      passwordSalt
    ) =>
      Subscriber(
        IdentityId(identityId.split("-")(0), identityId.split("-")(1)),
        firstName,
        lastName,
        fullName,
        email,
        avatarUrl,
        authMethod,
        OAuth1Info(oAuth1Secret, oAuth1Token),
        OAuth2Info(oAuth2AccessToken, oAuth2TokenType, oAuth2ExpiresIn, oAuth2RefreshToken),
        PasswordInfo(passwordHasher, password, passwordSalt)
      ),
      /* map object to a row */
      (o: Subscriber) => Some((
        o.identityId.userId+"-"+o.identityId.providerId,
        o.firstName,
        o.lastName,
        o.fullName,
        o.email,
        o.avatarUrl,
        o.authMethod.method,
        o.oAuth1Info.map(_.token),
        o.oAuth1Info.map(_.secret),
        o.oAuth2Info.map(_.accessToken),
        o.oAuth2Info.map(_.tokenType),
        o.oAuth2Info.map(_.expiresIn),
        o.oAuth2Info.map(_.refreshToken),
        o.passwordInfo.map(_.passwordHasher),
        o.passwordInfo.map(_.password),
        o.passwordInfo.map(_.passwordSalt)
      ))
    )
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `~` operator was used in Slick 1.x Now projections is done by tuple. So you have to do it like this:

```
def * = (identityId, firstName, ???) //and here rest of the mapping
```

You can read more here: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/upgrade.html#table-descriptions

Comment: Ah that would explain a lot. Thank you so much!